# How do I crop the text horizontally?

Tags: css, overflow, crop, clip

I need my content in a specific container. If the content increases horizontally, the container should crop, and if the content increases vertically the container should expand. here is my code:

```
<div style="padding:10px; width:602px; background:gold; clip: rect(0px, 602px, auto, 0px);">
  <div style="padding:10px; width:1000px; background:pink">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried using overflow but it is not working well.

here is my actual code http://jsfiddle.net/QeahW/7/ the dropdown div is not showing under the about company link. dont know how to solve it.

Comment: [`clip` only works in elements with `position: absolute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#clipping).

Comment: Use the same email to login, thus single account, don't create a new one

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want it like this? : http://jsfiddle.net/N4qvK/

I removed the widt on the inner container so that the inner block always remains withing the outerblock with the width.

Comment: In my scenrio the inner div must hav a width and the contents in it are crossing the width limit of outer div, with jquery those contents will be shown with minus margin on special events. cant change the jquery or other code i must have to do this with css. So outer div must crop the extra content.